# Не работает событие click внутри ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of items">
    <p>{{i.name}}</p>
    <button mat-button *ngIf="func();" (click)="editMessage()">edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Если вынести кнопку за пределы цикла, только функция editMessage() срабатывает. Внутри - 0 реакции

компонент:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  func() {
    return true;
  }

  editMessage() {
    console.log('asd');
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: нет ковычек после `*ngIf`

Comment: Это тут в примере опечатка, в коде все ок

Comment: все ок..наверное не в этом проблема https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kijsd8

Comment: Действительно все так работает. У меня только <li *ngFor="let i of items()"> а сама функция items() возвращает массив с объектами из localStorage. По сути там тоже самое что и если просто написать руками как у вас в примере. вот только click не работает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не работает событие click внутри цикла ngFor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982559/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-click-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-ngfor)