# Не работает событие click внутри цикла ngFor

Tags: angular, angular5

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of localStorMessage();">
    <p>{{i.name}}</p>
    <button *ngIf="canIEdit();" (click)="editMessage();">edit</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.scss']
})
export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  localStorMessage() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('history'));
  }

  canIEdit() {
    return true;
  }

  editMessage() {
   console.log('123');
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

функция localStorMessage() возвращает массив с объектами. На странице все выстраивается отлично, но не работает обработчик (click) на кнопке. 
Если же я руками напишу такой же массив:

```
    items = [
{name: 'name'},
{name: 'name2'}
]
```

и даже засуну в функцию

```
localStorMessage() {
 return this.items
}
```

То все будет работать отлично, обработчики на кнопках начнут реагировать. 
Почему если я принимаю данные из localStorage - кнопки ломаются? Функция localStorMessage() в обоих случаях возвращается один и тот же тип данных и все правильно отображается

Comment: `canIEdit` с параметром в `ts`...а в `html` - без

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц это неважно

Comment: и где ваш метод `editMessage`? я его не вижу

Comment: зачем вы создали дубликат [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982500/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-click-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-ngfor) !?

Comment: @overthesanity Поправил, просто тут забыл указать метод. Он просто пишет в консоль, ничего больше. На счет дубликата - хотел предыдущий удалить, т.к. изложил там хуже вопрос

Comment: создайте пример на stackblitz